# Qual o atalho no NetBeans para fechar todas os "+" das funções?

Tags: netbeans

Eu lembro que tinha essa função no NetBeans. É um atalho que fecha todos os (+) das funções ou `divs`.

Comment: Collapse all? Seria isso?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Boa parte dos atalhos podem ser obtidos em [PDF criado pela comunidade](https://netbeans.org/project_downloads/usersguide/shortcuts-80.pdf). Mas não tem o que precisa. Tem uma [página da Wiki de versão mais antiga com todos os atalhos](http://wiki.netbeans.org/KeymapProfileFor60). Não deve ter mudado muito. Especificamente o que deseja para PC/Mac:

| Ação | PC | Mac |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Collapse (hide) a block | Ctrl + Minus | Cmd + Minus |
| Collapse (hide) a block | Ctrl + NumPad Minus |  |
| Collapse (hide) all code blocks | Ctrl + Shift + NumPad Minus | Cmd + Shift + Minus |
| Expand a Collapsed Block (expand-fold) | Ctrl + Plus | Cmd + Plus |
| Expand a Collapsed Block (expand-fold) | Ctrl + NumPad Plus |  |
| Expand a Collapsed Block (expand-fold) | Ctrl + Equals Cmd + Equals |  |
| Expand all code blocks (expand-all-folds) | Ctrl + Shift + NumPad Plus |  |
| Expand all code blocks (expand-all-folds) | Ctrl + Shift + Plus | Cmd + Shift + Plus |
| Expand all code blocks (expand-all-folds) | Ctrl + Shift + Equals | Cmd + Shift + Equals |

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Java/Conceptual.md).

Answer (score 5):

O padrão é <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>-</kbd>. Mas você pode ajustar em Ferramentas -> Opções -> Mapeamento de tecla.

Referência: Resposta para a pergunta [Netbeans shortcut to minimise all functions?](https://superuser.com/a/342364/440513) no [superuser](https://superuser.com/)